# How to create an array from Firebase Data?

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a project where i need an array with elements from Google Firebase Data.
I have stored some membership plans details in Firebase like this:

```
"plans" : {
"3 Months Plan" : {
  "amount" : "1200",
  "planName" : "3 Months Plan",
  "savings" : "66",
  "validityInDays" : "90"
},
"6 Months Plan" : {
  "amount" : "1800",
  "planName" : "6 Months Plan",
  "savings" : "33",
  "validityInDays" : "180"
},
"Monthly" : {
  "amount" : "500",
  "planName" : "Monthly",
  "savings" : "99",
  "validityInDays" : "360"
}
```

Here i want an Array with elements like

```
String [] planNames = {"Monthly","3 Months Plan","6 Months Plan"};
```

i.e. an Array of all Plan Names, in an order

and an array of all plans amounts in same order as above array. i.e.

```
String [] planAmount = {"500","1200","1800"};
```

We can obtain a DataSnapshot of "plans" from follows:

```
database.getReference()
                .child("plans")
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull  DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    String [] planNames= //NEED HELP HERE
                    String [] planAmounts= //NEED HELP HERE
                   }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
```

Please guide me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onDataChange` the `snapshot.getValue()` will give you a `Map<String,Object>` of the `plans` data.

So let's first get the data from the snapshot:

```
Map<String,Object> map = (Map<String,Object>) snapshot.getValue();
```

Now you can get the keys of that map for your plan names:

```
String [] planNames = map.keySet().toArray();
```

And to pick the amount for each key:

```
String[] planAmounts = map.values.stream(r->r["amount"]).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Hey puf. When collecting the elements from a stream, the object that is returned is a List, so there is a conversion needed `String[] planAmounts = map.values().stream().map(r->r.getAmount()).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(String[]::new);`.

Comment: Darn, I hoped I got the magic incantation at the first try. :) Thanks for catching Alex. I updated the code in my answer, but let me know if I still got it wrong.

Comment: [values()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) is a method and [stream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) doesn't have any arguments. The filtering should be done using [map()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) according to a public field `.map(r->r.amout)` or the corresponding getter `.map(r->r.getAmount())`.